# ScrollTo... How to scroll to a certain number of pixels above a #?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position, scrollto

Okay, my issue is that I have a fixed navigation bar occupying 115 pixels of space at the top of the screen. When you scroll "to" a section, the fixed bar is covering part of the section. What I need it to do is scroll roughly 130 pixels (115 px for the nav bar and a little extra room so it doesn't look too cramped) above the section it's supposed to scroll to.

I [set up a quick and dirty JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DTLc/) so you can get the idea.

I assume I should be using offset or over in this, but they don't seem to do anything:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function(){//$.scrollTo works EXACTLY the same way, but scrolls the whole screen
$.scrollTo( this.hash, 1500, {easing:'elasout'});
});
```

[Here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) is where I got the script from and examples if they may help you.

I would also love to eliminate the #hash links that get appended to the URLs to keep from flooding the back history. There's really no need for them since the navigation bar is fixed and you can access any section of the site just by clicking a new link on the nav. But that's not a primary concern.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example! NOTE: Not using the plugin from your example - Tested only in Firefox & Chrome

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6DTLc/4/

```
  $('ul#navigation').find('a').on('click', function(e) {
      var
      link_href =  $(this).attr('href'),   
      $linkElem =  $(link_href),
      $linkElem_scroll = $linkElem.get(0) && $linkElem.position().top-115;           

      $('html, body')
          .animate({scrollTop: $linkElem_scroll}, 'slow');         

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now any way to add the {easing:'elasout'} effect like in the JSFiddle I posted?

Comment: Oh, cool, I figured it out. I just combined your code into the scrollTo code and it worked. :) Thanks~